# Chrome Extension pop up a new window on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension where you click on a button which launches an HTML page you created before. This is my button:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");       
var t = document.createTextNode("Click Me");
btn.addEventListener("click", popUpWindow);
btn.appendChild(t);                              
document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].appendChild(btn);
```

This is my function:

```
function popUpWindow() {
    window.open("window-child.html", "Accept", "width=400,height=300,0,status=0,")
}
```

This is my html page

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Demo of child window</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>   
        This is child window 
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside the manifest.json I added:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [ "window-child.html" ]
```

But when I click on the button it redirects me to https://www.linkedin.com/window-child.html, which gives:

> 404 Page Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chrome.extension.getURL()` to generate URL of the form

> chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]

Code:

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL("window-child.html");
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "_blank" target name as second parameter of window.open :

```
window.open("window-child.html","_blank", "width=400,height=300,0,status=0")
```

Comment: That's because the page does not exist.

Comment: Yes but I added it  to web_acessible_resources, so how can I access by clicking the button?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources says : These resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH], which can be generated with the extension.getURL method. Whitelisted resources are served with appropriate CORS headers, so they're available via mechanisms like XHR.